# how to decode youtube api v3 json response

Tags: php, json, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

here is my youtube json response

```
    query results:Array
(
    [kind] => youtube#searchListResponse
    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/_RyGfO1dwDRqY9aMf412I8xvZgw"
    [nextPageToken] => CAoQAA
    [pageInfo] => Array
        (
            [totalResults] => 1000000
            [resultsPerPage] => 10
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/vJBGevzCpIbHOcHu7AAc4WsQ92E"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => eHfMfHyiWYA
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2013-11-04T16:09:20.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCSvOdBJgMnTYsK-cZIGZSYQ
                            [title] => Ann Arbor - a test bed for driverless cars?
                            [description] => University of Michigan researchers work to make Ann Arbor the first American city with a shared fleet of connected and driverless vehicles by 2021. The cars of ...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eHfMfHyiWYA/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eHfMfHyiWYA/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eHfMfHyiWYA/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => michiganengineering
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/9Mm7w3esGwaHCTasG_67T33aULE"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => PRvGaCnfV-8
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2009-01-26T16:50:35.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCPkN7EcOJlQAzCLxaZSn_5g
                            [title] => Timelapse Cars
                            [description] => 
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PRvGaCnfV-8/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PRvGaCnfV-8/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PRvGaCnfV-8/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => frehleycomet
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/9_WnlpVsvx2WLKqdgxGXI3CRvBE"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => U60TfgpHqSc
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2013-07-01T23:23:59.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCULJH9kW-UdTBCDu27P0BoA
                            [title] => Are cars killing the Bicycle Kingdom?
                            [description] => Bike advocacy in the Bicycle Kingdom? China was once known as the Bicycle Kingdom but with the growth of the automobile, the nature of biking in Beijing is ...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/U60TfgpHqSc/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/U60TfgpHqSc/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/U60TfgpHqSc/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => llukitsch
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/_2N5Lkva8p_pbJqLf5K61gNPHL0"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => Xg5-oxTSM04
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2014-02-13T17:42:31.000Z
                            [channelId] => UC-Gu_VkJmS1FGxsrSddKvfg
                            [title] => Market America's 2014 World Conference: FreeBee Cars
                            [description] => Market America's 2014 World Conference in Miami featured FreeBee cars showcasing MA brands like Motives® Cosmetics and DNA Miracles™.
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Xg5-oxTSM04/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Xg5-oxTSM04/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Xg5-oxTSM04/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => MarketAmerica
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/VXZohXlA5kHPvrJ-rxpdEjUsaFY"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => yrcq5awviik
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2011-06-01T23:31:01.000Z
                            [channelId] => UC1URrXTrZ68pZZ4YDmT4WVQ
                            [title] => Ford's connected cars get street-smart
                            [description] => At AT&T Park in San Francisco, SmartPlanet correspondent Sumi Das talks to Ford's Mike Shulman about the company's research into intelligent vehicles.
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yrcq5awviik/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yrcq5awviik/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yrcq5awviik/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => SmartPlanetCBS
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/FWmwcjir_8QSK6eq5D5gsY-lWXQ"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => bFV7WU6UHaQ
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2014-05-14T10:59:48.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCI1H2wxkvshpCcUNNOEc4Gw
                            [title] => Google's Driverless Cars Take to the Streets
                            [description] => Google's self-driving car technology is not likely to be available for several more years. But the company is already beginning the job of making the public ...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bFV7WU6UHaQ/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bFV7WU6UHaQ/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bFV7WU6UHaQ/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => IBTimesUK
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/t7dSXvQ-37jK0DFYHxk4iP1o3-s"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => ifzSVGEHxMU
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2012-10-22T13:45:39.000Z
                            [channelId] => UC6s5vC0tCuStbt4d5dfhmjA
                            [title] => Project C.A.R.S: BMW Z4
                            [description] => Scott tries out the newest car to be added, the BMW Z4. Those of you waiting for Tekkit, it will return soon! Hound is currently in the process of moving! Pl...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ifzSVGEHxMU/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ifzSVGEHxMU/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ifzSVGEHxMU/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => scott2k44
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/RW6QW1hjACRmSo6Za1BzsP1gbSk"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => YZggnfolreA
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2015-05-08T21:32:35.000Z
                            [channelId] => UC87geOOB2rCWkJFtUUeEBsw
                            [title] => Project CARS vs. DriveClub | Graphics, Sound, Rain & Weather Effects Gameplay Comparison (PS4)
                            [description] => Comparing the biggest racing games available on the PS4, DriveClub (PS4 exclusive) and Project CARS (also available on PC and Xbox One). Both games are ...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YZggnfolreA/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YZggnfolreA/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YZggnfolreA/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => VideoGamesNL
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/OIAM0bSsr9oHqPwPPg3msZUqeMU"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => hJxFid8A0Xw
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2015-04-02T16:00:05.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCNjakstwb629k6IE9BualRw
                            [title] => Comedians In Cars Getting Coffee: Single Shot - Analogy Lad
                            [description] => Watch it on Crackle: [http://bit.ly/SingleShot] Jerry's special guests are Todd Barry, George Wallace, Sarah Silverman, Fred Armisen, Kevin Hart and Jimmy ...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hJxFid8A0Xw/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hJxFid8A0Xw/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hJxFid8A0Xw/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => Crackle
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "tbWC5XrSXxe1WOAx6MK9z4hHSU8/Q945pOROs0oCGIOcFFq66OWZZdw"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => I00AXDv8ncY
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2015-05-07T07:03:27.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCyQCcFWSh7MLAhdq2a_2jKA
                            [title] => Project CARS Online #1 - Los gehts! - Formula A @Monza | Wheel/Controller
                            [description] => Project CARS ist ein Motorsport Multiplayer-Simulation Spiel, entwickelt und veröffentlicht vom britischen Video-Spiel-Entwickler Slightly Mad Studios.
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/I00AXDv8ncY/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/I00AXDv8ncY/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/I00AXDv8ncY/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => 
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i want to extract video title, thumbnail, description from this json response using foreach loop

i tried this one but its gives me an error please help me to solve this issues.

my php code is

```
$link = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=rating&part=snippet&q=cars&maxResults=10&key={KEY}';

$video = file_get_contents($link);
$video = json_decode($video, true); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r("query results:");
print_r($video);
'</pre>';

foreach ($video->items as $data ){
    echo "{$data->snippet->title}";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$video` is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php), not an object, use `$video['items']`, the same with `$data` etc.

Comment: thanks can you please tell me the way of accessing the title in json response

Comment: `echo $data['snippet']['title'];`